# JAVA_OPTS for RedHat

Tags: java, tomcat, redhat

I am having hard time setting JAVA_OPTS for RedHat environment for tomcat 8. I need to load properties outside the tomcat install directory.
The folder structure:

`----/home/tomcat
     -----/apache-tomcat-8
     -----/remoteProperties`

I want to load the properties from the remote properties folder.

Here is the `setenv.sh` file content:

`JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -DPropertyPath=/home/tomcat/remoteProperties/collections"`

After deploying my war file it seems that this path is not correctly set:

FileNotFoundExcetpion
`/home/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.0.41/bin/home/tomcat/remoteProperties/collections/properties/logging/logback.xml`

As soon as I change content of `setenv.sh` and use relative path instead of absolute path:

`JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -DPropertyPath=../../remoteProperties/collections"`

It works as expected. Is it possible to set absolute path in JAVA_OPTS? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debugging the application I noticed that  `FileSystemResourceLoader` spring class is used to obtain some resources. Then I read in the documentation that it is mandatory to put prefix `file:` when using absolute path. Then I just had to change the content of `setenv.sh` script to:

`JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -DPropertyPath=file:/home/tomcat/remoteProperties/collections"`